# How do I fix this textureBackground identifier in Visual Studio 2017 using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I've experienced a problem when trying to declare an identifier. The main part is textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");
where textureBackground is the one being underlined

I've tried adding parentheses, changing uppercases, lower cases, check file locations, etc.

```
int main()
{
    //Create a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);

    // Create and open a window for game
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Scarful!!!", Style::Fullscreen);
    while (window.isOpen())

        // Texture for graphic on cpu
        Texture textureBackground;

        // Load graphic into texture
         textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");

        // Make Sprite
        Sprite spriteBackground;

        // Attach texture to sprite
        spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);

        // Set spritebackground to cover screen
        spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);
    {
        /* Handle player input */

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();

        }

        //Update Scene


        //Draw Scene
        window.clear();
        //Draw Game Scene
        window.draw(spriteBackground);

        //Show everything we drew
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? what is `Texture`? Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
while (window.isOpen())
    // Texture for graphic on cpu
    Texture textureBackground;
// Load graphic into texture
textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");
```

You are trying to do this:

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
    // Variable goes out of scope outside of the loop...
    Texture textureBackground;
}
   textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is not available anymore...
```

And since `textureBackground` is out-of-scope you cannot modify it anymore... I suggest you wanted...

```
// Texture for graphic on cpu
Texture textureBackground;

// Load graphic into texture
textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");

// Make Sprite
Sprite spriteBackground;

// Attach texture to sprite
spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);

// Set spritebackground to cover screen
spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    // Other code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Expanding the answer, just in case it isn't obvious, doing *heavy* things first (like loading an image), is encouraged. If you load the image inside `while` loop, you're repeating the same task over and over, which is not a good practice nor necessary.